# Add numbers to rows by block with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, duplicates, rows

I have data set like this :

```
City          Money   Code       Quantity
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4          
Denver        56.7    494681818   1
```

and i would like to add a number to each line by repeated City's block, i mean to get this :

```
City          Money   Code       Quantity Number
London        1.96    54645641    3         1
London        1.96    54645641    3         2
London        1.96    54645641    3         3
Madrid        200     158484      4         1
Madrid        200     158484      4         2
Madrid        200     158484      4         3
Madrid        200     158484      4         4
Denver        56.7    494681818   1         1
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You could use `countif` / `countifs`on the previous rows if sorted as shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIF with a variable range:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: It's doesnt work, i edited the topic and added a picture

Comment: That is not what your original question asked.  Changing the scope of the question after getting an answer is improper etiquette on this site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help